# Wait function/tween to complete before starting another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, gsap

I use TweenMax to animate divs with multiples `.mouseover` but I'd like one to complete before starting another one.

In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Leshautsdurant/eoL4ka84/), you can see the divs overlap if going to fast on the links.

Is there an easy solution for this ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var blocPrototypo = $("#wrap-image-menu");


  $("#prototypo").mouseover(function() {
    TweenLite.to(blocPrototypo, 1.4, {
      backgroundColor: "#24d390",
      ease: Circ.easeInOut
    });
    TweenMax.to(blocPrototypo, 0.5, {
      width: "39vw",
      ease: Circ.easeInOut,
      repeat: 1,
      yoyo: true
    });

    var allExcept = $(".all-img-menu").not(document.getElementById("img-prototypo"));
    TweenMax.to(allExcept, 0.9, {
      left: "0px",
      opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to($("#img-prototypo"), 0.7, {
      opacity: "1",
      width: "55vw",
      left: "-90px",
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      delay: "0.65"
    });

    TweenMax.to($("#line-pagination"), 0.5, {
      width: "76px",
      ease: Circ.easeInOut,
      repeat: 1,
      yoyo: true
    });

    $("#current-page").fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).text("01").fadeIn(1000);
    });

  });




  $("#esadvalence").mouseover(function() {

    TweenLite.to(blocPrototypo, 1.5, {
      backgroundColor: "#e12a1c",
      ease: Power1.easeOut
    });
    TweenMax.to(blocPrototypo, 0.5, {
      width: "39vw",
      ease: Circ.easeInOut,
      repeat: 1,
      yoyo: true
    });

    var allExcept = $(".all-img-menu").not(document.getElementById("img-esadvalence"));

    TweenMax.to(allExcept, 0.9, {
      left: "0px",
      opacity: 0
    });

    TweenMax.to($("#img-esadvalence"), 0.7, {
      opacity: "1",
      width: "55vw",
      left: "-90px",
      ease: Expo.easeOut,
      delay: "0.65"
    });

    TweenMax.to($("#line-pagination"), 0.5, {
      width: "76px",
      ease: Circ.easeInOut,
      repeat: 1,
      yoyo: true
    });

    $("#current-page").fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).text("02").fadeIn(1000);
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031320/stopping-next-hover-animation-from-happening-until-current-is-complete

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks for the link, I tried with `if($(this).is(':animated')){`and `else` but no reaction. Probably not smart...

Answer (score 1):

`TweenLite` and `TweenMax` have `onComplete` [callbacks](https://greensock.com/docs/TweenLite/eventCallback()) that can be used to await completion prior to beginning the next operation:

```
TweenLite.to(blocPrototypo, 1.5, {
    backgroundColor: "#e12a1c",
    ease: Power1.easeOut,
    onComplete: function() {
       // perform next operation
    }
});
```

There is also params you can pass via `onCompleteParams`, which you could perhaps use to indicate to some generic function the next operation you'd want to execute.

```
TweenLite.to(blocPrototypo, 1.5, {
    backgroundColor: "#e12a1c",
    ease: Power1.easeOut,
    onCompleteParams: [{ prop1: value1, prop2: value2 }],
    onComplete: function(someParams) {
       // perform next operation using passed params 
    }
});
```

Another approach could be using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or [jQuery Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) in combination with the `onComplete` event callback such as:

```
function foo() {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       TweenLite.to(blocPrototypo, 1.5, {
            backgroundColor: "#e12a1c",
            ease: Power1.easeOut,
            onComplete: function() {
               return resolve(true);
            }
        });       
   });
}

foo().then(function() {
   // perform next operation
});
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Maybe I should use `onComplete` but any idea about how I list the function to not animate ?

Comment: I don't want to start any function onComplete, but let allow a function to run after onComplete. And `onComplete` is added to a specific Tween. Can't it be on the whole function ?